# Can I use the firebase/gcloud emulators to develop on a project locally without enabling billing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a GCP/Firebase project that uses auth, FCM, Cloud Functions, Pub/Sub, and Firestore.

Is there a way I can use the emulators to set up a project that does not require billing to be enabled to do dev/testing?

From what I understand, FCM has no emulation component, so I would have to create an authentic firebase project for that component. Could I use an authentic firebase project for FCM and emulators for the rest?

Comment: You are asking 2 different questions here, please edit your question so we can happily assist you.

Comment: Only one question.